# iMacros get the ID of a div, not the content

Tags: parsing, extract, imacros

I am trying to learn iMacros (and avoid jscript or vbscript IF possible). I was reading **any resource i could find since yesterday** and the imacros reference does not have any helpful example of what i need.

All the methods I tried, will extract either the TXT or the HTM **content of an element**. My problem is that i have a div like this

```
<div class="cust_div" id="Customer_45621">
...content in here...
</div>
```

And the part i need to extract is **45621** which is the only dynamic part of the id attribute.
For example, between 3 customers, it could be

1. Customer_**45621**
2. Customer_**35123**
3. Customer_**85663**

All I need is the number. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=cust_div EXTRACT=HTM
```

Then you have to use EVAL and use in it JS scripting to extract the id. That is the only way. You can't cut the HTML code without JS, but you can use JS in iMacros with EVAL.

Comment: I am not very familiar with JScript, i supose i will need regular expressions for my task but i never had the upportunity to learn JScript (and especially regex in JS).. could you provide a sample please?

Comment: Go on stack JS chat and ask someone to make you a split function. This can be solved with use of text.split() method.

Comment: Found a solution which is
var test = '<div id="Customer_12345">test content</div>';
test = test.match("Customer_(.*)\"");
alert(test[1]);

but i cannot escape it correctly for iMacros... any ideas?